# Better to pad empty values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a document like this:

```
{
   email: "test@test.com",
   geo:
   {
       lat: null,
       lon: null,
       city: null,
       state: null,
       zip: null
   }
}
```

I have heard that it is sometimes better to "pad" empty values that are likely to be populated later, because then the document will have the correct amount of space allocated to it and will not need to be moved to a larger space if the document grows.

Is it better to set `geo` to `null` or am I correct to include the empty geo object in case it get's populated in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding can be a good idea, but not the way you do it.

MongoDB is a dynamically typed datastore. That means each field will only take as much size as the length of the key plus the length of the value. A BSON `nul` value only takes up a single byte (see [the BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) for more information). That means you are reserving space for the *keys* but not for the *values*. When you later replace the `null`s with actual data, that data will likely be much larger. This means your document will still grow and will likely still exceed the reserved space triggering a reallocation.

To pad effectively, pad with values which are as large as your expected data.

When you need some way to tell initialized and non-initialized documents apart, consider to not add the real keys, but instead add a single key `_reserved: "                             "` where the number of characters in the dummy-string is the expected length of the keys **and** values you want to add.

Comment: Oh, very interesting.  That actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @AbeMiessler sorry, but your edit was invalid. The javascript type `null` is represented by the BSON type `nul` with a single l. I made that distinction intentionally. When discussing storage allocation, it is important to keep in mind that BSON (the internal format of MongoDB) is not JSON.

Comment: Yeah, just looked that up when you rolled it back.  Also good to know :)